# Is there sugar with Optional chaining/nullish coalescing to prevent Typeerrors with say Array.map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, optional-chaining, nullish-coalescing

Is there any sugar to ensure that map will not typeerror using tools like [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)/[nullishcoalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)?

```
let x = {y: 1, z: 2};

x?.map(i => i); // Typeerror
Array.isArray(x)?.map(i => i); // Typeerror

let y = '1234';
y?.length && y.map(i => i) // Typeerror
```

Comment: These type errors seem to be correct. What's the intent here? You obviously can't call map on an object literal, boolean, or string.

Comment: Yeah Just looking for a terse way to avoid doing `Array.isArray(x) && x.map`

Comment: Ah okay! Got it. See if the below helps.

Comment: It's a bit strange (and often indicative of smelly code) to not know whether something is an array or not beforehand IMO. If you ever encounter a situation like this, consider fixing things upstream

Comment: @CertainPerformance Have used Optional Chaining with Nullish Colalescing inside JSX? Switching Components based on union data types Array|number like is pretty common usecase and it gets super elegant with Optional Chaining + Nullish Coalescing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These type errors seem to be correct. You obviously can't call map on an object literal, boolean, or string.

If you want to optionally call map anyways, you can continue the optional chaining with `?.(params)`:

```js
let x = {y: 1, z: 2};

x?.map?.(i => i);
Array.isArray(x)?.map?.(i => i);

let y = '1234';
y?.length && y.map?.(i => i)
```

Keep in mind this only checks if a property called `map` exists and is non-null/undefined. If it does exist but isn't a function, you'll still get an error.